# urlfetch IP range issue

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

My application requires as more IPs as possible to get it running, the google appengine urlfetch service change IPs all the time but i remains in a small range(my test),how to get more urlfetch service IPs?

I have tried to register more appids and google accounts and it doesn't work,the IPs are in the same range.

How can i do to solve this?Thanks!

Comment: Why does your app require "as more IPs as possible"? Also, note that sharding your app, and creating multiple accounts for this purpose, are violations of the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot control the IPs allotted to you by appengine directly.